# $\int(\int\phi(a-z)dz)dz=\Phi(a-z)$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Lets assume $\phi(a-z)$ is integrable.

Can I conclude that the following integral

$$\int\left(\int\phi(a-z)dz\right)dz$$

Can be expressed by a function $$\Phi(a-z).$$

So in result: 
$$\int\left(\int\phi(a-z)dz\right)dz=\Phi(a-z)$$

Comment: "Integrable two times"? That sounds odd...but I guess yes: you can call it whatever you want if the integral, whatever it is, exists.

Comment: Yeah, integrable two time is really useless :D. Edited my question. Thank you alot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\int\left(\int\phi(a-z)~dz\right)dz$

$=z\int\phi(a-z)~dz-\int z~d\left(\int\phi(a-z)~dz\right)$

$=z\int\phi(a-z)~dz+\int z~\phi(a-z)~dz$